# Using xr.open_dataset changes variable data (i.e. data point '43768' returns 'b'0' when read into xarray)

Tags: python, jupyter, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to read in some model data to compare to observation data. This data has a station_name corresponding to an actual bouy station name. However, when I read it into python using `xr.open_dataset(file)` It separates the 5 digit station name to a single character corresponding to a part of the station name. I'm noticing the station_name variable has dtype='|S1' which means it is only reading the one character at a time. I.e. It would break up station_name 41004 into b'4', b'1', b'0', b'0', b'4'. I guess I need a function to combine all of the separate strings and remove the b from the name and apostrophes and remove zero character entries. Is there a function to combine the 5 characters back to the original station_name and remove all of the b's and apostrophes? The netCDF function that does this correctly that I am looking for the equivalent of is `stationID = netCDF4.chartostring(station[:])` Here's the data variable readout in python:

```
Data variables:
station_name
(station, string40)
|S1
b'3' b'2' b'0' b'1' ... b'' b'' b''
array([[b'3', b'2', b'0', ..., b'', b'', b''],
    [b'3', b'4', b'0', ..., b'', b'', b''],
    [b'4', b'1', b'0', ..., b'', b'', b''],
    ...,<br />
    [b'6', b'3', b'1', ..., b'', b'', b''],
    [b'6', b'4', b'0', ..., b'', b'', b''],
    [b'6', b'4', b'0', ..., b'', b'', b'']], dtype='|S1')
```

**And in linux when I use ncdump -v station_name filename.nc:**

```
{  
dimensions:  
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (8 currently)  
        station = 240 ;  
        string40 = 40 ;  
variables:  
        double time(time) ;  
                time:long_name = "julian day (UT)" ;  
                time:standard_name = "time" ;  
                time:units = "days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00" ;  
                time:conventions = "Relative julian days with decimal part (as parts of the day)"  
 ;
                time:axis = "T" ;  
                time:calendar = "standard" ;  
        int station(station) ;  
                station:long_name = "station id" ;  
                station:_FillValue = -2147483647 ;  
                station:axis = "X" ;  
        int string40(string40) ;  
                string40:long_name = "station_name number of characters" ;  
                string40:_FillValue = -2147483647 ;  
                string40:axis = "W" ;  
        char station_name(station, string40) ;  
                station_name:long_name = "station name" ;  
                station_name:content = "XW" ;  
                station_name:associates = "station string40" ;  
        float longitude(time, station) ;  
                longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;  
                longitude:standard_name = "longitude" ;  
                longitude:globwave_name = "longitude" ;  
                longitude:units = "degree_east" ;  
                longitude:scale_factor = 1.f ;  
                longitude:add_offset = 0.f ;  
                longitude:valid_min = -180.f ;  
                longitude:valid_max = 360.f ;  
                longitude:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;  
                longitude:content = "TX" ;  
                longitude:associates = "time station" ;  
        float latitude(time, station) ;  
                latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;  
                latitude:standard_name = "latitude" ;  
                latitude:globwave_name = "latitude" ;  
                latitude:units = "degree_north" ;  
                latitude:scale_factor = 1.f ;  
                latitude:add_offset = 0.f ;  
                latitude:valid_min = -90.f ;  
                latitude:valid_max = 180.f ;  
                latitude:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;  
                latitude:content = "TX" ;  
                latitude:associates = "time station" ;  
        float hs(time, station) ;  
                hs:long_name = "spectral estimate of significant wave height" ;  
                hs:standard_name = "sea_surface_wave_significant_height" ;  
                hs:globwave_name = "significant_wave_height" ;  
                hs:units = "m" ;  
                hs:scale_factor = 1.f ;  
                hs:add_offset = 0.f ;  
                hs:valid_min = 0.f ;  
                hs:valid_max = 100.f ;  
                hs:_FillValue = 9.96921e+36f ;  
                hs:content = "TX" ;  
                hs:associates = "time station" ;  

// global attributes:  
                :product_name = "ww3.202104_tab.nc" ;  
                :area = "GLOBAL 1 deg grid lat 85" ;  
                :data_type = "OCO spectra 2D" ;  
                :format_version = "1.1" ;  
                :southernmost_latitude = "n/a" ;  
                :northernmost_latitude = "n/a" ;  
                :latitude_resolution = "n/a" ;  
                :westernmost_longitude = "n/a" ;  
                :easternmost_longitude = "n/a" ;  
                :longitude_resolution = "n/a" ;  
                :minimum_altitude = "n/a" ;  
                :maximum_altitude = "n/a" ;  
                :altitude_resolution = "n/a" ;  
                :start_date = "2021-04-01 03:00:00" ;  
                :stop_date = "2021-04-02 00:00:00" ;  
                :field_type = "3-hourly" ;  
data:

station_name =  
  "32012",  
  "34002",  
  "41049",  
  "41051",  
  "41052",  
  "41060",  
...  
  "64045",  
  "64046" ;  
}
```

I had to mark it all as code but it is output data above from xr_opendataset(file) and ncdump just to avoid confusion.

I tried to trim it so it wasn't so long but I thought to see the full ncdump would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems something related to decoding.

Maybe try this : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm

Look also at all the decoding options of xr.open_dataset() : http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html

Answer (score 0):

The station name was saved into characters that need to be converted back into readable strings using the `chartostring` command. This works to read the station names properly (alebeit reading in netCDF file with NetCDF4 and not xarray:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

modelfile = filepath+file
model = nc.Dataset(modelfile)
strings = model.variables['station_name'][:]
stations = nc.chartostring(strings[:])

Output: array(['32012', '34002', '41001', ... , '63115', '63117',
       '64045', '64046'], dtype='<U40')
```

I currently don't know the way to do it with xarray as this same code modified to read variables with xarry produces the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-87a0f3653b9d> in <module>
      1 # model.variables['station'][:]
      2 strings = model['station_name'][:][:]
----> 3 stations = nc.chartostring(strings[:])
      4 stations
AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'tobytes'
```

But, my above solution reading it in with NetCDF4 worked for me!